# Multiple scheduled-tasks invocation in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, scheduled-tasks

I have the following configuration in the beans.xml for Spring scheduled-tasks:

```
<task:scheduled-tasks>
    <task:scheduled ref="beanA" method="A" cron="0 0 0/1 * * *" />
    <task:scheduled ref="beanA" method="B" cron="0 0 0/5 * * *"/>
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

I want the first scheduled task to always run before second one. When I run the current code, the second task runs first, leading to few concurrency issues. Is there a precedence structure defined or a tag/id that I can use to define such a hierarchy?

Comment: The cron expression says 
`0 0 0/1 * * *` The command * will execute at 12:00am every 1st day of every month. 
`0 0 0/5 * * *` The command * will execute at 12:00am every 5th day of every month. 
What do you want to know that , please explain it.

Comment: @RobinSaxena Thanks, though I know what the cron expression means, I want to know a way how I can scheduled tasks in a specific manner in the spring beans.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a **[Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/)** scheduler which does precisely what you ask for. Read **[this](https://techannotation.wordpress.com/2012/07/17/spring-execution-scheduled-task/)** article for a step-by-step walkthorugh.

Alternatively, you may want to look into converting these tasks to a **[Spring Batch](http://projects.spring.io/spring-batch/)** job. From the documentation:

> Spring Batch provides reusable functions that are essential in processing large volumes of records, including logging/tracing, transaction management, job processing statistics, job restart, skip, and resource management.

Although it might be an overkill for scheduling two small tasks.

A third option is to you use a java **[ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)**. You can provide your own task queue to be used internally by it and you should not interact with the queue directly.

You can use a `PriorityBlockingQueue` constructed with a custom `Comparator` that returns which task goes first.

From the **[documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableScheduling.html)**:

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class AppConfig implements SchedulingConfigurer {
 @Override
 public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
     taskRegistrar.setScheduler(taskExecutor());
 }
 @Bean(destroyMethod="shutdown")
 public Executor taskExecutor() {
     return new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 2, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new PriorityBlockingQueue<Runnable>(20, new Comparator<Runnable2>() {
         @Override
         public int compare(Runnable2 o1, Runnable2 o2) {
             return o1.getPriority().compareTo(o2.getPriority());
         }
     }));
 }
}
```